# What is the best practice to check if an object is null in C++

Tags: c++, object, nullptr

I am working on a simple example. Let s say that I have an object `Object my_object` and I want to check if the object is null.

Therefore, I instantiate the object:

```
auto my_object = createMyObject(param_object_1);
```

The idea, is to check whether the object is null or not. If I am not mistaken (I am really new in C++), I have tried

**Check if reference is NULL**

I believe this is not an option (even if compiling) since references can never be NULL, so I have discarded it.

```
EXPECT_TRUE(my_object != NULL);
```

**Check if != to nullptr**

My next try has been to check if a pointer to the object is null.

```
auto my_object_ptr = std::make_shared<Object>(my_object);
EXPECT_TRUE(my_object_ptr != nullptr);
```

This code also compiles but I am not sure if this is the solution I was looking for. My intentions is to check if the pointer is pointing to a null object.

Is it a valid way to do it? If not, what s the best practise to check if the object is empty?

Comment: What type does `createMyObject` return? Is it just a `Object`? Objects can't "be null" in C++. Or is it a (smart) pointer? References can also not "be null" in C++, but comparing references to `NULL`, does compare the object referenced to `NULL`, not the reference as an entity itself.

Comment: `EXPECT_TRUE(my_object_ptr.get() != nullptr);` does the Trick.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ Just `EXPECT_TRUE(my_object_ptr)` probably does the same.

Comment: Objects are not null (in general), pointers can be null though.

Comment: Regarding your last snippet, unless you've done something insanely odd like specialize `std::make_shared<T>` for your object type, `EXPECT_TRUE(my_object_ptr != nullptr);` will *never* trip false. Either `std::make_shared` will *succeed*, or it will throw an exception (which you're not catching) well-past your test.

Comment: Objects themselves are not null. Never. Even pointer as an object is not null, it only may represent null (have nullptr value). I think you need to specify what you want to achieve/what problem you want to solve. I've checked your profile and I guess you want to just copy some solution from java/other language which may be very inconvenient ;)

Comment: Was trying to simplify a test. But thanks for confirming that objects can not be null. I guess the way to go then is something like EXPECT_EQ(my_object.param1, value1);

Comment: An object is a chunk of memory *interpreted* in a certain way. A pointer is the address of that memory, a reference is a way to use that pointer with certain guarantees.

Comment: In C++, unlike Java / C#, everything can be either a value type or a reference type. Unfortunately your use of `auto` obfuscates what that type is, we need to know what type `createMyObject`'s return value is. If `createMyObject` isn't a pointer, there's either no need to check for `NULL`/`nullptr` or you shouldn't try, because `Object{}` might not be the `null` that you are thinking, it might be a valid value (it could be an empty list, a 2-D vector initialized to `{0,0}`, an empty string, an integer with a value of 0, a giant class initialized with zeros, etc.).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I want to check if the object is null.

Congratulations, your `Object object` is not null. null is not a possible value for `object` to be.

A close analog might be to test that it is different to a default-constructed `Object`, if `Object` is default-constructable.

```
EXPECT_TRUE(my_object != Object{})
```

Comment: Note that @Caleth has buried something important deeply here. The author uses `{}` to construct the object so that all data members are initialised. Otherwise the program behaviour could be undefined during the evaluation of `!=`. Considering this must mean the answer is deserving of an upvote. One's coming...

Answer (score 1):

1. `nullptr` is called a **null pointer literal**. You can also use `NULL` or `0` (zero), but prefer nullptr for it removes some ambiguities.
2. You can use `nullptr` with pointers but **not with references or objects**.
3. C++ does **not initialize pointers by default**. So, `int* p;` points to a random address (`0` included).
4. To **test against null** you can simply write `if (!p)...` or `if( nullptr == p )...`. Smart pointers are designed to behave in the same way as naked ones, so you can test for null in the same way.
5. A **null** pointer is **not necessary an error**.
6. A **non-null** pointer is not necessary a valid pointer - you forgot to initialize it, for instance (see 3). Another example is a pointer to an object whose storage duration has ended (@user17732522).
7. Although **references** can be think as pointer in disguise, the language **enforces initialization**; that is they cannot point to a random location – except for this strange case: `int& r = r;`. The rationale behind this construct is the backward compatibility with C (I do not know if the latest standards changed this).

Comment: The wording of 3 and 6 is a bit dangerous. It makes it sound as if it is ok to test an uninitialized pointer against `nullptr`. But it isn't. A better example for an invalid pointer is a pointer to an object whose storage duration has ended.

Answer (score 0):

Objects are never `NULL`. References are never `NULL`. `std::make_shared` does return not a shared pointer that compares equal to `nullptr`, when deallocation fails `std::bad_alloc` is thrown.

To check if a pointer is not `nullptr` you do

```
if ( raw_ptr != nullptr)
```

To check if the pointer stored by a shared pointer is not `nullptr` you can make use of the conversion to `bool`:

```
if ( some_shared_ptr )
```